# rake task for import data from txt file ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I would like to import the data from txt file to database in Ruby. I have tried to create a rake task to do so and struggling with finding a elegant way of doing it.

### My Rake task so far:

```
desc "Import schools." 
  task :import_schools => :environment do
    File.open(File.join(Rails.root, "imports", "schools.txt"), "r").each do |line|
        if ! line.valid_encoding?
          s = line.encode("UTF-16be", :invalid=>:replace, :replace=>"?").encode('UTF-8')
          s.gsub(/dr/i,'med')
          description, time, standards, books, choices = s.strip.split("\t")
          u = ImportResult.new(:description => description, :time => time)
          u.save
      end
    end
  end
```

### My txt file datas like:

```
primary 23484775884 standard:fifth book:science choice:maths name:Joseph city:London
secondary 46537728836 standard:fourth book:english choice:maths name:Jain city:Manchester
.........
```

I want to insert each of these record into `ImportResult` database and ignore `name` and `city` of each record.

### Expected Result

```
ImportResult Table:

id: 1
description: primary
time: 23484775884
standard: fifth
bookname: science
```

Thanks

Comment: You seem to have several questions. Can you narrow it down to one?

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question and hope that helps to understand. @jordan

Comment: Does each line in the text file always have the same fields in the same order?

Comment: Yes @jordan It always has the same fields in the same order. But with some `key:value` pair types. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main challenge here is this: How do I turn a line from the text file into a hash of attributes I can pass to `MyModel.create`? Since each line in the text file has the fields in the same order, one simple approach is to just use a regular expression:

```
LINE_TO_ATTRS_EXPR = /
  \A
  (?<description>\w+)\s+
  (?<time>\d+)\s+
  standard:(?<standard>\w+)\s+
  book:(?<book>\w+)\s+
  choice:(?<choice>\w+)\s
/x

def line_to_attrs(line)
  matches = LINE_TO_ATTRS_EXPR.match(line)
  Hash[ matches.names.zip(matches.captures) ]
end

p line_to_attrs("primary 23484775884 standard:fifth book:science choice:maths name:Joseph city:London")
# => { "description" => "primary",
#      "time" => "23484775884",
#      "standard" => "fifth",
#      "book" => "science",
#      "choice" => "maths" }
```

Here I've assumed that the `time` field will always be a string of digits (`\d+`) and that fields are separated by whitespace (`\s+`).

Another approach is to split the line on whitespace and then split each of those parts on the colon (`:`) and use the part on the left as the key and the part on the right as the value. Since the first two fields are in a different format, we pull them off the array first. Then we can use `each_with_object` to put them into a Hash, skipping the keys we don't want:

```
def line_to_attrs(line)
  attrs = {}
  attrs[:description], attrs[:time], *rest = line.split(/\s+/)

  rest.each_with_object(attrs) do |part, attrs|
    key, val = part.split(':')
    next if key =~ /^(name|city)$/
    attrs[key.to_sym] = val
  end
end
```

Whichever method you choose, you can now apply it to each line to get a hash of attributes to pass to `ImportResult.create!`:

```
File.open(Rails.root + "imports/schools.txt", "r") do |file|
  ImportResult.transaction do
    file.each_line do |line|
      ImportResult.create!(line_to_attrs(line))
    end
  end
end
```

Note that I used `File.open(...) do ...` instead of `File.open(...).each` do. Using `open` with a block ensures that the file will be closed when the operation is complete, even if errors occur.

If your input is large, however, you may find that this is slow. That's because you're creating an ActiveRecord object for each line and performing one insert at a time. Doing it in a transaction helps, but only so much. If performance becomes an issue, I suggest looking at the [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) gem.

Comment: Thank you very much and really appreciate your explanation that made easy to understand and follow.

Comment: I got an syntax error on the line `File.Open` of your second example and what is `file.each_line` where `file` is not declared anywhere?

Comment: I have an `Argument Error : Invalid type UTF-8` :-(

Comment: I've fixed the syntax error and the `file` error you mentioned. As for the UTF-8 error I can't diagnose it without the actual data. In my code I didn't use the `line.encode ...` code you had in your question just to make the answer easier to read, but you may still need it in your code.